# Laravel and AWS Elastic Beanstalk - File Permissions

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created a Laravel app and deployed it to an EC2 instance using Elastic Beanstalk. Everything seems to work except that PHP can't write to the `storage` directory so I get this error:

```
Error in exception handler: The stream or file "/var/app/current/site/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" 
could not be opened: failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in /var/app/current/site/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:84
```

This looks like a permissions problem to me, so I've tried using the instructions  at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html to set the permissions.

I have one file `01permissions.config` in the `.ebextensions` directory:

```
commands:
  storage_permissions: 
    command: chmod -R 755 $EB_CONFIG_APP_ONDECK/site/app/storage
```

I get the following errors in server logs:

```
[ERROR] Command storage_permissions (chmod -R 755 $EB_CONFIG_APP_ONDECK/site/app/storage) failed
[DEBUG] Command storage_permissions output: chmod: cannot access â€˜/site/app/storageâ€™: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had ignored the logs directory so it wasn't on the server at all. It's not that the server couldn't write to it, it's that it didn't exist.

The default permissions for an instance created by Elastic Beanstalk are:

File `664`

Dir  `775`

They are deployed and owned by the Apache user.

Comment: What do you mean you had ignored the logs directory? I am having the same issue but nowhere in the project .gitignore do I ignore the storage directory. Does it have to do with all of the .gitignore files in each folder? (logs, sessions, etc.)

Comment: I think I had ignored logs in .gitignore_global in my home directory. Take a look for that. If not, put an empty .gitignore file in the logs directory because Git doesn't track empty directories.

Comment: Thanks @Josh. We are using Jenkins to push our builds and it turns out it was removing .gitignore files (which were all that were in those folders) and then removing the folders because they were empty. I added some dummy files to each folder and it fixed the disappearing folder problem immediately.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else with this problem... this would have worked:

```
container_commands:
  01storage_permissions:
    command: "chmod -fR 755 /var/app/ondeck/app/storage"
```

Comment: the path should be `/var/app/ondeck/storage`